Japanese Particle Usage
On my practice JLPT test, there is a questions which reads
両親に買ってもらった着物（　）大学の卒業式に出席した。
The options are
を、が、で、に
Why is the answer で to this question? I tend to get mixed up with inserting particles sometimes, so I'd also appreciate any information on why the other particles are NOT correct. Thanks!

Unfortunately, you simply have to remember that, in Japanese, you need to use the particle で to indicate the clothes one is wearing while doing something. で is a widely used particle that expresses the tool used (e.g., 箸で食べる "eat with chopsticks") or the manner of an action (e.g., 裸で泳ぐ "swim naked").
I know it's hard to remember the correct particles for all cases. Conversely, Japanese people who learn English also struggle with choosing the correct prepositions for years. In English, 着物で would correspond to "in a kimono", but this "in" would look surprising and strange to Japanese speakers at first.
